# How can I use this class as a web service?

Tags: apex, webservices

How can I use this class as a web service?

```
global class CreateAccountRecordsBatch implements Database.Batchable<sObject>{

   global String Query;
   global CreateAccountRecordsBatch(){

   }

   global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC){
   system.debug('this is suahfrf');
    Query='select id from Account limit 10';
      return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
   }

   global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Account> scope){
   system.debug('thisdjsnhd exec');
     List<Account> accountList = new List<Account>();
     for(Account A : scope){
        Account objA = new Account(Name = 'Test');
        accountList.add(objA);
     }
     insert accountList;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a separate class and have a webservice method that you use to call the batch class. It would be something like this:

```
global class ExposedWebservices{

    webservice static void runBatch(){
        CreateAccountRecordsBatch cls = new CreateAccountRecordsBatch(); 
        Database.executeBatch(cls);
    }

}
```

Although if your batch class only operates on 10 records, you probably shouldn't use batch apex.

---

Once you have your webservice class set up, you can try calling it from an external application, or maybe through a custom button in salesforce, or something else.

As an example, you could create a button that executes the following javascript:

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/37.0/connection.js")} 
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/37.0/apex.js")} 
sforce.apex.execute("ExposedWebservices","runBatch",{});
```